# Json data of specific page is not displaying in Reactnative TypeError:

Tags: react-native

I want to display the only Title of the specific page number 4267. But it shows TypeErro: undefined is not a function (this.state.data.map.... .

Note: it works when I use the general url for pages. But to use just one page for example as this one:
return  fetch("http://192.168.1.88/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/4267")

then it displays the error.

```
  export default class App extends Component {
      constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = { data: [] };
      }
      getDatass() {

             return  fetch("http://192.168.1.88/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/4267")
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(responseJson => {
              this.setState({ data: responseJson });
            })
            .catch(error => {
              console.error(error);
            })
        );
      }

      componentDidMount() {
        this.getDatass();
      }
      //here code

      // end of functions

      render() {

        let articles = this.state.data.map(function(articleData, index) {
          return (
            <Card>
              <CardItem>
                <Body>
                  <Text> {articleData.id}</Text>
                </Body>
              </CardItem>
            </Card>
          );
        });
```

and here is the json data:

```
id: 4222,
date: "2018-12-30T07:41:55",
date_gmt: "2018-12-30T07:41:55",
guid: - {
rendered: "http://192.168.1.1.63/?page_id=4222"
},
modified: "2018-12-31T10:38:24",
modified_gmt: "2018-12-31T10:38:24",
slug: "mypage",
status: "publish",
type: "page",
link: "http://192.168.1.1.63/mypage/",
title: - {
rendered: "mypage"
},
content: - {
rendered: "<p>[vc_row][vc_column][vc_column_text]</p> <h1>Afghanistan is a good city</h1> <p>[/vc_column_text][/vc_column][/vc_row][vc_row][vc_column][vc_single_image image=”4188″][/vc_column][/vc_row]</p> ",
protected: false
},
excerpt: - {
rendered: "<p>[vc_row][vc_column][vc_column_text] Afghanistan is a good city [/vc_column_text][/vc_column][/vc_row][vc_row][vc_column][vc_single_image image=”4188″][/vc_column][/vc_row]</p> ",
protected: false
},
author: 1,
featured_media: 0,
parent: 0,
menu_order: 0,
comment_status: "closed",
ping_status: "closed",
```

Answer (score 0):

that is the json data that doesn´t work right?, mayge it's because the general json is an array , and that's the reason you are able to use the ".map " function, but the individual page is a json, you can't use map in a json . instead you can render conditionally

```
render() {
   if(Array.isArray(this.state.data)){
        let articles = this.state.data.map(function(articleData, index) {
          return (
            <Card>
              <CardItem>
                <Body>
                  <Text> {articleData.id}</Text>
                </Body>
              </CardItem>
            </Card>
          );
        });}else{
      return(
            <Card>
              <CardItem>
                <Body>
                  <Text> {this.state.data.id}</Text>
                </Body>
              </CardItem>
            </Card>)
}
```

you can improve this, but the idea is there

Comment: Thank you... your answer helped me but now I got this problem. Even I have used htmlview. <p>[vc_row][vc_column][vc_column_text]</p> <h1>Afghanistan is a good city</h1> <p>[/vc_column_text][/vc_column][/vc_row][vc_row][vc_column][vc_single_image image=”4188″][/vc_column][/vc_row]</p> ", . It also displays the p sections along the rows and all.

Comment: I don't know the reason for that ,  that's because i don't know the way you are managing the custom components you have . It may help using a Flatlist component instead of that map function you have, then if you have only one item , wrap it as the first item of an array and it would render normally . That's something you need to handle yourself ;)